# Replacing <Frameset> with <Object>, Can I dynamicaly change one of the Object URLs without reloading the entire page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, asp-classic, frameset

I'm replacing a classic asp website with asp.net, c# code behind. Need to be HTML5 compliant, so I replaced the existing Frameset page with a similar page using the HTML object data Attribute. There are 4 URLS that make up this page. Using Frameset, you could update one of the URLs without refreshing the entire page using target="parent.name of frame". The 3 frames would be unchanged while the 4th frame would be an entirely new URL.  Is there a similar way to update a URL in the object page ? If not, is there an alternative to Framesets and Iframes that is HTML5 compliant and will let you update dynamically ?

```
<div id="header" class="header">
<object data="https://localhost:44365/HEADER.aspx" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%">   </object>
</div>
<div id="main" class="row">
<div id="column2" class="column left">
    <div id="left_top" class="left_top">
        <object data="https://localhost:44365/MainMenu.aspx" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    </div>
    <div id="left_bottom" class="left_bottom">
        <object data="https://localhost:44365/RevTable.aspx" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="column1" class="column right">
    <object data="https://localhost:44365/MAIN.aspx" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you use ajax to load the content of each individual div?

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, I'm not sure I understand. How would I load the webpages using AJAX ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm typing this off the top of my head, and I haven't tried the code. But you should be able to load the content using jQuery Ajax. This will be the basics of it. How and where you want to script to be called, and with what variables will have to change to suits your needs.

```
<script>
function getContent(url, target){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        success: function(response) {
            $(target).html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div onClick="getContent('https://localhost:44365/HEADER.aspx','#header')">Click me to load header.</div>
<div onClick="getContent('https://localhost:44365/NEWURL.aspx','#left_bottom')">Click me to load the left bottom div with a new URL.</div>
```